# Please let me know what is difference between 2 different SELECT SQL in ProC

Tags: sql, c, proc

I use ProC and there are 2 different ways to invoke `SELECT` in SQL.
I thought that both of them got ERROR. Because there are two `SELECT` columns,  but host variable is 1.
Not as expected, 1. got an error but 2. didn't get an error. I don't know why.

Please let me know what is difference between two different `SELECT`s in SQL.

1.

```
EXEC SQL SELECT USER_ID, USER_NAME
            INTO : h_user_id
            FROM USER;
```

2. 

```
char temp[1024] = "SELECT USER_ID, USER_NAME INTO FROM USER";

   EXEC SQL DECLARE lookup_user CURSOR FOR

   EXEC SQL OPEN lookup_user;

   while(1)
   {
     EXEC SQL FETCH lookup_user INTO :h_user_id
    }
```

Comment: Why have you tagged db2 ?   Pro*C is for embedded-SQL with Oracle rdbms. Fix your tags.   The first query (static SQL) is incorrect because the number of host variables (=1) does not match the number of columns in the result-set (2).   The second query would be used in dynamic SQL.

Comment: thank you for your opinion(edited tags :) ). Yes I know second one is dynamic SQL. but the second one also got 1 host variable and 2 columns.  is it allowed it in dynamic SQL?

Comment: The second query has no host-variables, it's just a piece of text that happens to contain a query that could return a 2-column result-set, if correctly prepared and executed at runtime.

Comment: Ah OK, I got a handle on it. I have to study how dynamic SQL working. Thank you for answering this stupid question :).